# I cannot install my application in my mobile using Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I have set proper paths and installed plugins (Dart and Flutter) in my Android Studio but I have always seemed this error below and same in Visual Studio Code?

```
Downloading Gradle Wrapper...                                       0.6s
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX1971 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Downloading Gradle Wrapper...                                       0.6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check

Android Studio -> New -> ProjectStructure -> Modules.
Please check the full Project Structure.

I hope it helps.